Using a single DBContext with a model for multiple schema generated at runtime in EF Core
Considering a sample application with the data structure:
Calculations: Id, Value

The application should update the database structure at runtime to add a new table recognized by schema. Then it should add the calculation data to this table. Finally, it should read data according to schema.
Example of tables generated at runtime with schema names a, b, c, etc.:
a.Calculations
b.Calculations
c.Calculations
etc. 

What is the best practice for it in EF core using a single Db Context, and a single model class without using inheritance?
Model:
public class Calculation
{
    public int? Id;
    public int? Value;
}

DB Context which receives the schema as an argument. It also uses ModelCacheKeyFactory to return the cached model according to the schema:
public partial class SampleDBContext : DbContext
{
    public string Schema { get; }
    public DbSet<Calculation> Calculations { get; set; }

    public SampleDBContext(DbContextOptions<SampleDBContext> options, string schema) 
        : base(options)
    {
        Schema = schema;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Calculation>().ToTable("Calculations", Schema);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=SampleDB;")
                .ReplaceService<IModelCacheKeyFactory, CustomModelCacheKeyFactory>();
    }
}

Generating data: It should update the structure of the database first which is a problem here.
public void Generate(string schema)
{
    // Updating the database structure is missing here!
    // ...
    //
    var optionBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SampleDBContext>();
    var context = new SampleDBContext(optionBuilder.Options, schema);
    var calculation = new Calculation { Value = 1 };
    context.Calculations.Add(calculation);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

Loading data:
public List<Calculation> Load(string schema)
{
    var optionBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SampleDBContext>();
    var context = new SampleDBContext(optionBuilder.Options, schema);
    var data = context.Calculations.ToList();
    return data;
}

Usage:
Genarate("a");
var resultsA = Load("a");
Genarate("b");
var resultsB = Load("b");
Genarate("c");
var resultsC = Load("c");


See docs: Multiple schemas

I don't think you can map the same class multiple times, e.g., to different schemas. You can, however, execute custom SQL and have it mapped to a class. For example, something like this:
var resultsA = context.Database
.SqlQuery<Calculation>($"SELECT ... FROM a.Calculations")
.ToList();

var resultsB = context.Database
.SqlQuery<Calculation>($"SELECT ... FROM b.Calculations")
.ToList();

Just make sure you include all the relevant columns for the mapping. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries.
Beware, no schema generation/migration supported with this approach.

Even if this query approach is the best possible solution, your solution does not address how to manage migration and code-first modeling.

@Mahdi: very true, I will mention it in my response
